# Keras: what is the difference between model.evaluate_generator and model.predict_generator

Tags: keras

I used keras data augmentation to perform image classification (ten-class images). The last training epoch gives the results as follows:

```
Epoch 50/50
4544/4545 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.7628 - acc: 0.7359 loss:  0.762710434054
New learning rate:  0.00214407973866
4545/4545 [==============================] - 115s - loss: 0.7627 - acc: 0.7360 - val_loss: 0.5563 - val_acc: 0.8124
```

Then evaluate the trained model by:

```
scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator,1514) #1514 testing images
print("Accuracy = ", scores[1])
```

It leads to the following results:

```
('Accuracy = ', 0.80713342132152621)
```

The accuracy is not exactly the same as that obtained in the last training epoch. I don't understand the difference, even though it is marginal.

Further, model.predict_generator gives totally different result that is an array shown as follows:

```
array([[  4.98306963e-06,   1.83774697e-04,   5.49453034e-05, ...,
      9.25193787e-01,   7.74697517e-04,   5.79946618e-06],
   [  2.06657965e-02,   2.35974863e-01,   2.66802781e-05, ...,
      2.16283044e-03,   8.42395966e-05,   2.46680051e-04],
   [  1.40222355e-05,   1.22740224e-03,   7.52218883e-04, ...,
      3.76749843e-01,   3.85622412e-01,   6.47417846e-06],
   ..., 
   [  9.94064331e-01,   1.30184961e-03,   1.08694976e-05, ...,
      1.25828717e-06,   2.29093766e-05,   9.01326363e-04],
   [  7.10375488e-01,   2.01397449e-01,   3.10241080e-06, ...,
      3.66877168e-10,   1.66322934e-05,   1.93767438e-08],
   [  8.13350256e-04,   2.67575349e-04,   6.79878794e-05, ...,
      8.63052785e-01,   9.70983761e-04,   8.54507030e-04]], dtype=float32)
```

I don't know what the matrix represents, and what is the difference between model.evaluate_generator and model.predict_generator.

It is noted that the resultant array has a shape of 1514*10. The array should be the prediction probabilities at each class for the set of testing images. If so how to compute a confusion matrix based on the result?

Answer (score 33):

`predict_generator` takes your test data and gives you the output.

`evaluate_generator` uses both your test input and output. It first predicts output using training input and then evaluates performance by comparing it against your test output. So it gives out a measure of performance, i.e. accuracy in your case.

Comment: Great answer! I have a question, because evaluate_generator returns average accuracy in this case, how can I know the variance of accuracy? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I solved setting shuffle = False in the generator.
My guess is that if the train batch isn't a multiply of elements, the last incomplete batch is not considered and having shuffle the excluded elements are random and that change sigthly the result.

Answer (score -2):

To plot a confusion matrix you need to import the said from sklearn

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

To plot the confusion matrix, the test_labels, classes (number of output of the last fully connected layer, the output layer). It seems you have got this part figured out. Next you need both the test_labels and predictions to be of the same dimension for which you can use np.reshape and np.transpose to get the desired results. For syntax and definition you can follow the below mentioned links

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html

Now to plot the confusion matrix you can use the code from sklearns documentation

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html

Thank you. Hoping that would help you.